How can I create a taproot address that time-locks the bitcoin sent to it until a specified blockheight?
I'd like to create a taproot address that timelocks any funds sent to it until a specified blockheight in the future.
How can I do this using Bitcoin Core's QT Console?
I am also curious to know about creating a timelocked taproot multisig address that works in the same way.
